# Spring Boot File Conversion Microservice as a Cloud Foundry User-provided Service

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, cloud-foundry

I have a Spring Boot REST Microservice which expects an input file and converts this file to other formats using ffmpeg like so
`ffmpeg -i <INPUT_FILE> -vf 'scale=320:-2' <OUTPUT_FILE>`

I am calling this command at the moment in a Java ProcessBuilder and referencing the container location of the input and output files after pushing the microservice to PCF.
The ffmpeg binary and the input file are packaged in the `jar`file
I understand I need to use cloud storage like NFS or S3 to specify the locations, but that is a secondary matter now.

My idea is to make the Microservice a PCF User-provided Service, so that bound Apps will supply the location of the input and converted files.
Also since there are different conversion functions, I have corresponding endpoints for each conversion function.

All examples I have seen with respect to Microservices have to do with Databases whereby you specify information like URL and credentials to access the external database,
which does not shed any light into what I have in mind.

So I have the following questions:

1) Is it possible to simply convert the running Conversion Microservice into a PCF User-provided Service? I know of the `CUPS` command, but I am not sure what to supply as Parameters, also since I have several endpoints

2) How could bound Apps call the endpoints of this Service and provide the locations of the input and output files.

**I will appreciate code snippets if possbile**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do should be possible, but not quite in the way you describe it.

For starters, you can use a user provided service to pass details about a microservice between apps. Thus if you create a conversion microservice, you can pass information about the microservice to consuming apps via a user provided service.

Where I think you need to change your plans a bit is with the consuming apps. You can't pass the input/output files via a user provided service, at least not without sharing storage between the two and you don't want to go down that road. It's limiting as all apps have to share the storage and it will have scaling limits.

Instead what you'd want to do is to put the location and credentials required by a consuming party in the user provided service (this is what you're seeing with databases). For example, you'd probably need the hostname or route to your microservice and likely a user token/secret or username and password (that way you know who's making requests to your service).

Your consuming app could then read the information out of the bound user provided service and use that to contact your conversion microservice. At that point, it would be up to the consuming app to understand the API that you expose from your microservice so that the consuming app can send the file to be converted to the microservice and retrieve the processed file. You'd likely send/retrieve files over HTTP, and if I may make a recommendation you probably want to look at using the [claim check pattern](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/StoreInLibrary.html) on your service since doing conversions can be time consuming.

Hope that helps!

Comment: So what you are practically saying is that:

1) Specify the **URI and Credentials** of the storage location `(say NFS or S3)` as parameters to the user provided conversion service via `CUPS`

2) Let the consuming app retrieve this information from the `vcap_services` variable and use it to pass the input file to the endpoint

3) The consumimg app should go the same location to retrieve the converted file say via another endpoint. 

Would appreciate confirmation sir!

Comment: `1) Specify the URI and Credentials of the storage location (say NFS or S3)` -> S3 or compatible - Yes.  NFS/SMB - Not quite. You can't use these with a user provided service. Your CF provider needs to have the NFS/SMB service broker installed, because the service needs to be configured in a special way so that the foundation mounts the requested volume into your container.  Otherwise, yes. That's the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Mikusa. 
You have been extremely helpful like always, appreciative